# Validate email address in javascript using state machine

Tags: javascript, regex, email

I have read lots of questions about email validation in javascript, and never found a really satisfactory solution.

Example: [Validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Problem is, most answers use regex, and the regex required for email is too complex to understand.

I have read that the best way to validate emails, is to use a state machine to match the spec. I can't imagine this is too complex, but can't find any examples online of non-regex email validation in javascript. Are there any out there?

Comment: The best way to validate IMO, `/[^@]+@[^@]/`, then send confirmation email.

Comment: Do you want to check if the email is exists or only valid?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: It should work fine, is open ended regex.

Comment: @elclanrs: Ah, yes, quite.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Answer (score 0):

You should stick with `^[^@]+@[^@]+$` ..That's it..

1>Validate the mail with above regex

2>Send mail to that email address.

3>Email Id is valid if you get any response from that Id...

---

In case you want to prevent users from making mispells you can use [mailcheck.js](https://github.com/Kicksend/mailcheck)

[image]

---

[Stop Validating Email Addresses With Complicated Regular Expressions](http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/)

Highlight:

> Think about it this way: I register for your website under the email
>   address qwiufaisjdbvaadsjghb@gmail.com. C’mon. That shit’s probably
>   going to bounce off of the illustrious mail daemon, but the formatting
>   is fine; it’s a valid email address.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was trying to do it with a state machine, not a regex.